# Spring MVC 3 JSON

Tags: java, json, jsp, spring-mvc

I have been stuck on this problem for a very long time. I have looked on resources on the Internet but cannot find where I am going wrong. I have configured Spring MVC to send and receive JSON. When I invoke a RESTful service from the web browser for @ResponseBody the Object that is being returned is returned as JSON. However, when trying to invoke a @RequestBody I am unable to.

Below is the code:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
     <display-name>WebApp</display-name>

     <context-param>
        <!-- Specifies the list of Spring Configuration files in comma     separated format.-->
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/history-service.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>

     <listener>
        <!-- Loads your Configuration Files-->
        <listener-    class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
     </listener>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>history</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>history</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

     <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list>
```

history-service.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>     
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="jacksonMessageChanger" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jacksonMessageChanger"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>-->
```

Controller class

```
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/history/*")
   public class ControllerI {

@RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-            type=application/json"})
public @ResponseBody UserResponse save(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
    UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
    return userResponse;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody UserResponse delete() {
    System.out.println("Delete");
    UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
    userResponse.setSuccess(true);
    return userResponse;
}
```

When invoking /webapp/history/delete I can receive JSON.

Index.jsp

```
    <%@page language="java" contentType="text/html"%>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h2>WebApp</h2>
<form action="/webapp/history/save" method="POST" accept="application/json">
    <input name="userId" value="Hello">
    <input name="location" value="location">
    <input name="emailAddress" value="hello@hello.com">
    <input name="commitMessage" value="I">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when invoking the /save I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerE
xceptionResolver handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod
WARNING: No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/history/sa
ve', method 'POST', parameters map['location' -> array<String>['location'], 'use
rId' -> array<String>['Hello'], 'emailAddress' -> array<String>['hello@hello.com'], 'commitMessage' -> array<String>['I']]
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. All I want to do is send JSON through JSP to the Spring MVC Controller so the @RequestBody can be turned deserialized into Java from JSON.

I hope you can help.

Comment: Why there is space in "save" like "sa ve"?

Comment: Actually, there is no space. I just copied from Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chage **accept="application/json"** to **enctype="application/json"** on your HTML form.

Spring can not parse you post data for you did not set the current headers.
When use @RequestBody the default accept enctype is application/json.
try to one of this:

1. set post headers="content-type=application/json" on you html form or js post function.
2. set you controller to accept headers="content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Edit

The enctype must the same as headers.
Ok, the code now looks like one of those:

```
// the one
@RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody UserResponse save(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
    UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
    return userResponse;
}


</form>
<form action="/webapp/history/save" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input name="userId" value="user">
    <input name="location" value="location">
    <input name="emailAddress" value="hello@hello.com">
    <input name="commitMessage" value="I">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


// the other
@RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
public @ResponseBody UserResponse save(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
    UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
    return userResponse;
}


</form>
<form action="/webapp/history/save" method="POST" enctype="application/json">
    <input name="userId" value="user">
    <input name="location" value="location">
    <input name="emailAddress" value="hello@hello.com">
    <input name="commitMessage" value="I">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Try one of those above.

> I get the following error:
>
> HTTP Error 415: The server refused this request because the request
>   entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the
>   requested method ().

Comment: So if I follow step 2 then Spring will detect the JSON sent and deserialize in the Object? If I follow this approach, will the code be in JSP: <form action="/webapp/history/save" method="POST" accept="application/json"> 
    <input name="userId" value="Hello"> 
    <input name="location" value="location"> 
    <input name="emailAddress" value="hello@hello.com"> 
    <input name="commitMessage" value="I"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-                  type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}) // headers = {"content-                    type=application/json"} 
public @ResponseBody UserResponse save(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception { 
    UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse(); 
    return userResponse; 
}

Comment: <form action="/webapp/history/save" method="POST" enctype="application/json"> 
    <input name="userId" value="user"> 
    <input name="location" value="location"> 
    <input name="emailAddress" value="hello@hello.com"> 
    <input name="commitMessage" value="I"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

Comment: I get the following error:

HTTP Error 415: The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().

Comment: ok, I have tried both as you mentioned. Still I get the same error Http 415. Do I need to set something in Spring?

Answer (score 1):

Your not posting JSON data. You have to use javascript or something to convert the form inputs into JSON. Jquery is very useful for this. Or change your controller to accept

```
headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

FYI, you can use FF or Chrome's developer tools to see the headers when you submit the form. Specifically the Network panel (for Chrome). 
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

I believe its the Web Console in firefox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_the_Web_Console

Using Jquery to post form input:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
     var frm = $("#MyForm); // In the JSP/HTML give your form an id (<form id="MyForm" ...)
     var dat = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());

     $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: url,
          data: dat,
          success: function(hxr) {
              alert("Success: " + xhr);
          }

          dataType: 'json'
       });
     );
 });
</script>
```

More infor here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Can I not directly invoke from JSP to Spring MVC?

Comment: Sure, just make sure your controller will accept the content type your form is sending.

Comment: Could you please give an example on how to send JSON through JSP please? So I can invoke my Spring MVC. Just a simple 1. So we have 4 attributes: userId, location, commitMessage and emailAddress. How can I do this in JSP?

Comment: @user1646481, see my edited response. The link at the end is to JQuery's post api call. You can also take a look at JQuery's ajax api call.

Comment: Thanks, do I have to use jQuery. Actually, what I am looking for is sending JSON to Spring MVC. Is there no way of writing JSP code to send JSON. For the example you mentioned will I need to download any libariries?

Comment: Yes, change your Spring controller to accept form input (header = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded") instead of JSON. You can also change it to accept both. Or change the form's encoding type: `<form method="post" enctype="application/json" ...`